I can not return userRole in next-auth
I have a problem. This is my options file it is located in app/api/auth/[...nextauth]
import GitHubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const options = {
    providers : [
        GitHubProvider({
            profile(profile){
                console.log("Profile Github: ", profile)

                let userRole = "Github User"
                if(profile?.email == "x@gmail.com"){
                    userRole = "Admin"
                }
                console.log("User Role:>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ", userRole)

                return {
                    ...profile,
                    role: userRole
                }
            },

            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET
        }),

        GoogleProvider({
            profile(profile){
                console.log("Profile Google: ", profile)

                let userRole = "Google User"

                return {
                    ...profile,
                    id: profile.sub,
                    role: userRole
                }
            },

            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET
        })
    ],

    callback: {
        async jwt({token, user}){
            if (user) token.role = user.role
            return token
        },

        async session({session, token}){
            if(session?.user) session.user.role = token.role 
            return session
        }
    }
}

this is my member page
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";

import { options } from "../api/auth/[...nextauth]/options";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

const Member = async () => {
    const session = await getServerSession(options);

    if (!session) {
        redirect("/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=/Member");
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Member Server Session</h1>
            <p>{session?.user?.email}</p>
            <p>{session?.user?.role}</p>
            {JSON.stringify(session)}
        </div>
   );
};

export default Member;

I am using nextjs 14.2.5 and next-auth 4.24.7. I have tried to clear cache (cookies, session & localhost) and restarted the server over and over but still i can not get the user.role what i get is name and email. I need a solution.
Please help
I was expecting to access session?.user?.role but i can not despite of me returning it in the options file
